# Way in Pulumi to run a function only when pulumi up deploys resources and not during a preview?

Tags: pulumi

Is there any way in a [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/) project to run a function only when pulumi is actually deploying the resources to the cloud during the `pulumi up` after the user accepts to deploy?

I have an scenario were I need to run a custom code for aws like this:

```js
myAwsModule.putResourcePolicy({policyName: "AWSLogDeliveryWrite20150319",/*...*/});
```

I don't think I can make this change using `@pulumi/aws` because it is a special ResourcePolicy that aws sometimes automatically generates but sometimes it could not exist yet, and pulumi seems to require to have a deterministic knowledge of the resource existing or not.

I want to avoid the code from above example to run during a `pulumi preview` or during a `pulumi up` if the user doesn't accept to actually run it, so I was hoping there would be something like this:

```js
if (!pulumi.isPreview) {
  myAwsModule.putResourcePolicy({policyName: "AWSLogDeliveryWrite20150319",/*...*/});
}
```

Is there something like that or any other way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pulumi.runtime.isDryRun`

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/pulumi/runtime/#isDryRun

Different casing for all SDKs, but it's available across all

Comment: so `isDryRun()` returns true during a preview, right?
What about during a `pulumi refresh`?
and during a `pulumi up` when the user selects "no" to deploy the changes?
The documentation is not very clear for us to understand those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `pulumi.runtime.isDryRun` function will tell you if you're in a `preview`. That may be all you need. If you need something more flexible than this then you may want to look into the [Pulumi Automation API](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/using-pulumi/automation-api/).

The Automation API has a little bit of a learning curve and the documentation is relatively sparse IMO, but it's a game changer if you have very large stacks you need to decompose or if you need a more dynamic workflow.

If you were to use the Pulumi Automation API, you could easily have any arbitrary code run before or after you do a `preview` and inform your stack of the output of this arbitrary code.